# Dynamic SQL based on values in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to dynamically create SQL, I have a table like this :

```
Operator  Value
BETWEEN   0 AND 21
BETWEEN   21 AND 50
```

I need to write a query that will basically execute:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE 22 Operator Value
```

And this should return the second row of the table above.

Comment: what and all `operator` values you are considering in this question??

Comment: @pratikgarg it could be ANY SQL operator.

BETWEEN,
<,
>,
IN

etc.

Comment: So _every_ [documented operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174986.aspx) is fair game? What will `Value` contain for `EXCEPT` and `INTERSECT` operators? Or bitwise XOR?

Answer (score 3):

You can go with this, give it a try

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Test') is not null drop table #Test
create table #Test (Operator nvarchar(20), Value nvarchar(20))

insert into #Test (Operator, Value)
values
('BETWEEN', '0 AND 21'),
('BETWEEN', '21 AND 50')

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM #Test WHERE 22 '

declare @sqlHelper nvarchar(max) = 
                (select Operator + ' ' + Value
                        + ' and Value = '''+Value+''''
                        from #Test 
                        where 22 <= Cast(RIGHT(Value, 2) as int) and
                              22 >= Cast(LEFT(Value, 2) as int))

select @sql + @sqlHelper 
execute (@sql + @sqlHelper)
```

rextester: http://rextester.com/OJTIW53082

query exectued is: `SELECT * FROM #Test WHERE 22 BETWEEN 21 AND 50 and Value = '21 AND 50'`

results:

```
+----------+-----------+
| Operator |   Value   |
+----------+-----------+
| BETWEEN  | 21 AND 50 |
+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: I don't think that does what you think it does. That returns all rows from the table if even one row matches the `value` column. The @sql would be `SELECT * FROM #test WHERE 22 BETWEEN 21 AND 50`

Comment: change `@sqlHelper` to include: `and value = '''+Value+''''` to correct, like so:`select Operator + ' ' + Value  + ' and Value = '''+Value+'''' from #Test where 22 <= cast(right(Value, 2) as int)`

Comment: @SqlZim i am not following you, can you take over this query and add another answer with changes you just said?

Comment: There you go, now it will only return the 2nd row from the table as requested in the question. You were most of the way there. -- oops, I edited your answer instead. Is that alright with you?

Comment: if this is what is needed i kinda misunderstood the question, i thought it's needed just to build query based on given number, not actually to select again from same table of given `Operator` and `Value`. But if this is what fix his problem, it's all good

Comment: That was my understanding of the question, the last line is "And this should return the second row of the table above." Without that additional `and` in the where clause your query returned all rows from the table.

Comment: Awesome. well 2 people will always come to solution faster then just 1, thanks for giving me the pointers